# Loop to delete multiple items in list...c#

Tags: c#, linq, loops, foreach

I have a method that searches a database for all the customers with the same company name and then returns a list of their ID numbers and for now I have them being saved to a text file so I can confirm that it worked.

The problem I am having though, is accessing that list of ID numbers and going back and deleting them. In the following code I use a request that will cancel a customer by their ID number. I use a foreach loop that was supposed to get the list of ID's and delete them all but instead it just deletes one and not a different one each time, it deletes the same one each time, rather attempts to, I just get the exception back saying **you are trying to delete a customer that was already deleted**. Please send any suggestions on what I am doing wrong!

```
SearchRequest _request;
CancelRequest _request2;

SearchResponse _response;
CancelResponse _response2;

public void ArrangeRequest() {
    _request=new CustomerSearchRequest();
    _request.Company="Test Inc. ";
}
```

```
var customerIds=_response.Customers.Select(c => c.CustID).ToList();

foreach(var custID in customerIds) {
    _request2=new CancelRequest();
    _request2.CustID=custID;
    _request2.Company=_request.Company;
}
```

```
public void Response() {
    var ws=new RunEngine();

    _response=ws.SearchCust(new AppHeader(), _request) as SearchResponse;
    _response2=ws.CancelCust(new AppHeader(), _request2) as CancelResponse;
}
```

Comment: The cancelRequest does the delete. I don't have to manually write the code for that. It is an object that was automatically generated.

Comment: @GrantThomas Presumably the collection of cancellation requests are sent to the server via some other method.  The point is simply that the only thing the OP doesn't know how to do is property create the cancellation object; he's capable of using them to actually delete the data on his own.

Answer (score 4):

You are reusing `_request2` field. Instead of storing single cancel request in field, use list of requests:

```
List<CancelRequest> _cancelRequests;
```

Then create and add all requests to this list:

```
var customerIds = _response.Customers.Select(c => c.CustID);
_cancelRequests = customerIds.Select(custID => new CancelRequest { 
                          CustID = custID,
                          Company = _request.Company
                  }).ToList();
```

And process those requests one by one later.

Comment: What is `_request.Company` here?

Comment: @IronMan84 It's what the OP used.  If that's not what it should be, we have no idea of knowing what belongs there.

Comment: I think after assigning new instance to `_request` in question, this line could be removed

Comment: @IronMan84, that is the value that is to be searched in the database to find common customers and put them in a list to be deleted

Comment: You can use `AsEnumerable` rather than `ToList` on the first line to ensure that the second `Select` is performed client side without forcing the entire query to be pulled into memory and without creating a list that isn't ever used.

Comment: @Servy I believe that requests should be used later (as original _request from question), thats why I use list :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It may or may not make sense for `requests ` to be a `List`, we can't know without knowing how it's used.  But `customerIds` doesn't need to be a list, it can just be an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your issue doesn't happen directly with list, because your `CancelCust` can take one `Request` at a time. I actually cannot understand where the earliest code fragment you post should be, so I just name it `NowhereMethod`!

I've also revised for your code, corrected something like `_request.Company=_request.Company;`. I further deduced all your class hierarchy from the usage according to the code you've post.

As you stated, the deletion is done by `CancelRequest`, however, as I mentioned above, it can only take one `Request` at a time, and the `Request` is inferred that it saves the information only about one customer. Thus, I'm thinking that your issue can simply solve by rewriting the `Response` method.

You can still think the problem is about to make them a list like other answers shown that, those are correct way to use Linq. Nevertheless, you might need to decide for a correct place to put in some class, and either design a method in a correct way to take the list.

So, it's the code, I deduced and tried to correct; note that I use *fields* instead of those probably are *properties*, and put only those are needed.

You might want to take a look of the comments in the code.

```
partial class Listener /* I named it, to put your code */ {
    SearchRequest _request;
    CancelRequest _request2;

    SearchResponse _response;
    CancelResponse _response2;

    public void ArrangeRequest() {
        _request=new CustomerSearchRequest();
        _request.Company="Test Inc. ";
    }

    void NowhereMethod() {
        var customerIds=_response.Customers.Select(c => c.CustID).ToList();

        foreach(var custID in customerIds) {
            _request2=new CancelRequest();
            _request2.CustID=custID;
            _request2.Company=_request.Company;
        }
    }

    public void ResponseOriginal() {
        var ws=new RunEngine();

        _response=ws.SearchCust(new AppHeader(), _request) as SearchResponse;
        _response2=ws.CancelCust(new AppHeader(), _request2) as CancelResponse;
    }

    public void Response() /* tried to correct */ {
        var ws=new RunEngine();

        _response=ws.SearchCust(new AppHeader(), _request) as SearchResponse;

        var customerIds=_response.Customers.Select(c => c.CustID).ToList();

        foreach(var custID in customerIds) {
            _request2=new CancelRequest();
            _request2.CustID=custID;
            _request2.Company=_request.Company;

            // Seems it should be like this
            // but note the assignment might be wrong, it's according to what `CancelCust` returns
            // for the correct way to make it a list of Customer is appeared in other answers 
            _response2=ws.CancelCust(new AppHeader(), _request2) as CancelResponse;
        }
    }
}

partial class Customer {
    public String CustID;
}

partial class Response {
    public List<Customer> Customers;
}

partial class Request {
    public String Company;
    public String CustID;
}

partial class SearchResponse: Response {
}

partial class CancelResponse: Response {
}

partial class SearchRequest: Request {
}

partial class CancelRequest: Request {
}

partial class CustomerSearchRequest: SearchRequest {
}

partial class AppHeader {
}

partial class RunEngine {
    public Response SearchCust(AppHeader appHelper, Request request) {
        // I don't know what it's like
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Response CancelCust(AppHeader appHelper, Request request) {
        // I don't know what it's like
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The `Request` and `Customer` can either be declared as

```
partial class Customer {
    // Company was not appearing used in the code
    public String CustID;
}

partial class Request {
    public String Company;
    public String CustID;
}
```

or

```
partial class Customer {
    public String Company;
    public String CustID;
}

partial class Request: Customer {
}
```

will not break the code.

Answer (score 0):

`_request` appears to be a lone variable, and not a list. It would then only do one record since you're newing it up every single time through the loop and not storing any previous loop values in a list.

Edit: You'd want to do something like this:

```
    var requestList = new List<CancelRequest>();
    var customerIds = _response.Customers.Select(c => c.CustID).ToList();
    foreach (var custID in customerIds)
    {
        _request = new CancelRequest(); 
        _request.CustID = custID;
        _request.Company = _request.Company;
        requestList.Add(_request);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the same problem is still happening, still trying to delete the same ID number.

Comment: added additional code to the original to explain it better hopefully. For now I am trying a few additional things on my part to see if I can figure it out but any suggestions are great! Thanks!

Comment: Just going through the code while I was debugging I saw that when I saw '_request2.CustID = custID', it already assigns custID the same ID number but I guess it doesn't change it to the list of numbers we stored in the List.